# TFS 2012 - error TF218017 SharePoint site cannot be created

Tags: sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010

I have an out of the box install (SharePoint and TFS on same box, external SQL server) and when I attempt to create a project I get an error as per the screenshot.

[image: 218017]

I have checked under Central Admin -> Site Settings -> People and Groups - Farm Administrators.

I can see my user domain account is listed, so technically I am a farm administrator and can do what i want.

Any idea why I get this error and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the service account for TFS a farm admin in SharePoint. If your service account is network service, use the name of the tfs server with the $ symbol. For example, domain\tfsserver$

Good luck!